# How to debug non-rooted Nexus 5 Android 5.0.1 tethering issue?

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, tethering, dns

I normally use tethering a lot but hadn't since the 5.0 update and so didn't notice this issue. Now my Nexus 5 is at 5.0.1 and today I needed to tether and found that it doesn't work.

Phone is Nexus 5, with 5.0.1, build LRX22C. Computer is MBP OS X 10.9.5.

IP address is allocated on tethering, but every query results in "Server not found" error. I think that I found a related issue here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82545

The additional problem I have is that using different name servers (8.8.8.8) does not solve the problem.

The surprising thing is that tethering works on my wife's phone with the exact same configuration without any problem.

I am at a loss how to debug this. Any pointers would be appreciated.

It goes without saying that my data connection works, the carrier isn't blocking it in anyway.

Edit 1: So looks like that statement was not entirely true. I am roaming in the US using Roam Mobility SIM card. And this is what I found on their site:
http://www.roammobility.com/support/Cannot_use_Hotspot_with_Nexus_5.html

So I switched the preferred network to 3G from LTE, and the tethering works. It is annoying to not understand why this happens. Any ideas?